# Linux utility for Disk health Monitoring

Tags: linux, health-monitoring, hard-drive

We are looking into implementing an in-memory utility which can recover the system in case of disk/filesystem lockup. This utility has to detect the lockup and take corrective action like rebooting or just shutting down interface.

The server platform is Gentoo Linux 2.4

Any suggestions on - any existing utility or which scripting method will work best (expect, native C++)?

Answer (score 2):

you'll want S.M.A.R.T. monitoring tools (smartmontools)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.

Note that not all statistics correlate with impending drive failure, and sometimes (for some brands and models) you may need to pass in special flags or you will get garbage. See the wikipedia article for which attributes really indicate danger.

The command is `smartctl`. You may need to be `sudo`. `smartctl --all` will give a summary of all drives, spinning them up very briefly to check their health.

Answer (score 2):

What type of errors are you looking for?

`smartmontools` and `smartd` which ship with most distros should be able to help you. They work at a low level with the disk.

- [SMART on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.)
- [smartmontools](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki)

Comment: Well the real issue is that these servers get stuck at time with no disk read/write activity but network keeps working. So we want to detect this and recover from that. Our server do have smartctl utility. But how would that help in recovery (i.e. shutting down network interface)?

Comment: If your looking for disk activity you could wrap something like `iostat` or for a cleaner way of doing it probably go and fetch the data from wherever it's buried in `/proc`

Comment: Well ours is more of a disk lockup scenario (may be caused by physical elements or purely filesystem corruption). So some program/script has to run periodically to detect that. And that program/script has to survive that failure and perform recovery action. So I may need suggestions on how that implementation will look like?